# Postgres column type for storing numbers with many decimals

Tags: postgresql, column-types

I need to store in a column values like `0.0000003215218845`

What type does my column needs to be? I've tried making it `real` or `float` but when I run a select query, to value I get is `3.21522e-07`

What type does my column needs to be in order for the select query to return fully `0.0000003215218845` value?

Comment: `numeric` or`decimal` (synonyms) - [Postgres numeric types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html)

Comment: you can store them in float ok. `3.215218845e-07` is equal to `0.0000003215218845`

Comment: Float lacks real precision. If you need an exact answer it should be avoided. Numeric has a limit that's in the thousands of characters and still be accurate, but it's slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to control how a floating point number is converted to a string, use the [`to_char`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) function:

```
SELECT 0.0000003215218845::double precision;

     float8
-----------------
 3.215218845e-07
(1 row)

SELECT to_char(0.0000003215218845::double precision,
               'FM90.9999999999999999');

     to_char
------------------
 0.00000032152188
(1 row)
```

The difference in value is the rounding error.

Use `numeric` for values with arbitrary precision.

Comment: Finally something that works. From what I've read in order to perform calculations exactly I would need either numeric or decimal. But how should I specify the precision and scale to fit all the values up to 20 decimals for instance. I need to do the calculations exactly so a type which isn't stored exactly won't work

Comment: Use a type like `numeric(21,20)` (that would be for one position before the decimal separator and 20 after).

Comment: Note that you do not HAVE to declare the precision.

Answer (score 2):

See postgres documentation: [numeric-types v.9](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-numeric.html) or [numeric v.11](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-numeric.html). could help.
But you must be aware:

- The tool, you do your queries with, often does not return the data in full resolution. The numbers might be stored correctly, you must probably change the format, how you output it.
- float and double are stored as binary so the data might be rounded before being stored. So perhaps if you want to store decimal data in their exact form, the fixed-point types might be more suitable for your application.